# How to access external SSD when it does not show up in Windows Explorer or the Disk Management?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I connected an external SSD via USB to my windows 10 computer.  I see it listed in my Device Manager.  But it does not show up in the Disk Management tool and it does not show up in Windows Explorer.  Here's an image:

[image]

When I go to Device Manager, right click KingFast, then update driver, it says my drivers are up to date.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I want to be able to copy files into my external KingFast SSD.

Comment: In Disk Management, what happens when you select Action and then Scan (or Rescan) Disks?

Comment: When I scan, I see a new Disk with the expected filesize of 238GB shows up as "Not initialized", so that's good progress.  When I try to either Initialize it as GUID or Master Boot Record, I get the message "This request could not be performed because of an I/O device error".  Problem occurs even after I restart my computer.  This KingFast SSD use to be from a laptop that stopped working suddenly.  Am I looking at a malfunctioning drive then?

Comment: Does the disk have a drive letter assigned to it? If so, from an elevated CMD prompt do a "Chkdsk /R X:", but replace the X with the drive letter. Ultimately I suspect a bad drive but that check should give you more info.

Comment: "This KingFast SSD use to be from a laptop that stopped working suddenly" - Don't you think this is key information that should be in OP?!

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me

Windows
Open Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management. Click on Disk Management and see if the SSD is shown in the bottom right window pane. If it is, right click on where its labelled as Disk 1, Disk 2 etc and select "Initialise Disk" (this may come up automatically when you go into Disk Management).

In Windows 10, 8, 7 & Vista, right click on the area to the right of the disk label and choose "New Simple Volume". Continue with the wizard by choosing size, drive letter & formatting of the partition.

In Windows XP, right click on the area to the right of that and choose "New Partition". Then "Primary Partition" in the partition wizard. Continue with the wizard by choosing size, drive letter and formatting of the partition.

Comment: If you read OPs comments updating their question, you'll note they have tried this and received further errors. When answering questions, it is in your best interest to make sure you understand the situation as thoroughly as possible.